# error: undefined reference to `vtable for class'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm have an error in the following code. I tried to fix it with many of the options given here but could not.

Here is .h

```
#ifndef JUEGO2PRUEBA_H
#define JUEGO2PRUEBA_H
class juego2Prueba: public QGraphicsView
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    juego2Prueba();
    ~juego2Prueba();
private slots:
    void on_buttonLeft_clicked();
    void on_buttonRight_clicked();
    void on_buttonUp_clicked();
    void on_buttonDown_clicked();

private:
    void mueveMomia();
    void mejorMovMomia(QChar direccion);
    void finalizaJuego();
    bool puedeMoverse(int x, int y,QChar mov);
    void creaTablero();
}
```

and .cpp

```
juego2Prueba::juego2Prueba(){
    //CODE
}

void juego2Prueba::on_buttonRight_clicked()
{//CODE}

void juego2Prueba::on_buttonLeft_clicked()
{//CODE}
void juego2Prueba::on_buttonUp_clicked()
{//code}
void juego2Prueba::on_buttonDown_clicked()
{//code}
void juego2Prueba::mueveMomia(){
//code}
void juego2Prueba::mejorMovMomia(QChar direccion){
//CODE}
void juego2Prueba::finalizaJuego(){
    this->hide();
    timerPerdio->stop();}
bool juego2Prueba::puedeMoverse(int x, int y, QChar mov){
//code}
void juego2Prueba::creaTablero(){
//more code}
juego2Prueba::~juego2Prueba(){
}
```

The error:

```
C:\Users\Barrionuevo\Desktop\build-MummyAlgoritmos-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\juego2prueba.o:-1: In function `ZN12juego2PruebaC2Ev':
C:\Users\Barrionuevo\Desktop\MummyAlgoritmos\juego2prueba.cpp:7: error: undefined reference to `vtable for juego2Prueba'
C:\Users\Barrionuevo\Desktop\MummyAlgoritmos\juego2prueba.cpp:7: error: undefined reference to `vtable for juego2Prueba'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you full-clean, restart QtCreator, and full-rebuild yet ? Clarification of what "many options given here" you tried would probably help eliminate the "been there, done that" suggestions.

Comment: Did you run qmake? It needs to be re-run after adding or removing signals if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Perhaps QGraphicsView class is not available to the linker

Comment: I ran into the same problem.  I did what @SurvivalMachine suggested which was to  run qmake. Problem fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Undefined reference to vtable" means in qt that

1. there is a problem with the signal slot mechanism. A signal has been
   sent but the reference to the slot object is invalid. So try to find
   out which signal/slot relation is corrupted, maybe you have never
   assigned a model to the view
2. there are old compiler generated moc files which are still there. Just delete the complete debug and release folder.

Comment: This is a linker error. No signal slot connections have been made at link time.

Comment: in my case the issue was in old generated files, removing those files fixed the problem, Thanks.